# vscode findFiles returns nothing but npm glob returns correct results

Tags: file, visual-studio-code, jestjs, glob, vscode-extensions

I'm writing and vscode extension in which I need a list of the test files inside workspace.

To find the test files I'm using the default `testMatch` from the `jest.config.js` which is:

```ts
[
    '**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)',
    '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)'
]
```

My problem is that `vscode.workspace.findFiles` returns empty array and I cannot set it up to get correct results, but using [`Glob`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) package the output is correct.

```ts
    protected async findTestFiles(
        matchTestsGlobPatterns: string[]
    ): Promise<vscode.Uri[]> {
        const testFilesUris: vscode.Uri[] = [];
        const glob_testFilesUris: vscode.Uri[] = [];
        const { name: workspaceName, workspaceFolders } = vscode.workspace;
        if (workspaceName === undefined || workspaceFolders === undefined) {
            throw new Error(`No active workspace${!workspaceFolders ? ' folders' : ''}.`);
        }
        for (let folderIdx = 0; folderIdx < workspaceFolders.length; folderIdx++) {
            const folder = workspaceFolders[folderIdx];

            // - by vscode.workspace.findFiles
            for (let patternIdx = 0; patternIdx < matchTestsGlobPatterns.length; patternIdx++) {
                const currentPattern = matchTestsGlobPatterns[patternIdx];
                const pattern = new vscode.RelativePattern(
                    folder.uri.fsPath,
                    currentPattern
                );
                const files = await vscode.workspace.findFiles(
                    pattern,
                    '**/node_modules/**'
                );
                testFilesUris.push(...files);
            }
            console.log('by [vscode.workspace.findFiles]', testFilesUris.length);

            // - by npm Glob
            var glob = require('glob');
            for (let patternIdx = 0; patternIdx < matchTestsGlobPatterns.length; patternIdx++) {
                const currentPattern = matchTestsGlobPatterns[patternIdx];
                const files: any[] = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    glob(
                        currentPattern,
                        {
                            absolute: true,
                            cwd: folder.uri.fsPath,
                            ignore: ['**/node_modules/**']
                        },
                        function (err: Error, files: any[]) {
                            if (err) {
                                return reject(err);
                            }
                            resolve(files);
                        }
                    );
                });
                glob_testFilesUris.push(...files);
            }
            console.log('by [npm Glob]', glob_testFilesUris.length);
        }

        
        // @todo: remove duplicates.
        return testFilesUris;
    }
```

The example console output of this function for some project is:

```powershell
by [vscode.workspace.findFiles] 0
by [npm Glob] 45
```

Project structure:

```ts
 rootFolder
     src
        __tests__
             files.test.ts
             ...
             utils
                 array.test.ts
                 ...
```

So my question is how do I call `vscode.workspace.findFiles` to get correct results, or is there known problem with this function?

---

I have found some kind of answer to the question.
The problem is `?(x)` in patterns. The `vscode.workspace.findFiles` does not work with this pattern as other packages do. If remove it from mentioned glob patterns they work except the `.jsx | .tsx` files are ommited.

Answer (score 1):

After deep dive into vscode github's issues I have learned ([here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10851)) that `vscode.workspace.findFiles` does not support extended patterns like `?(patterLike)`